# BlackBerry 6 and 7 application development failure

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I have successfully setup all the IBM mobile first environment. I then created a  mobile app named "BB6APP" with the BlackBerry 6/7 environment.

When trying to run the application build in Studio, I get the following error:

> Failed to deploy application 'BB6APP' to MobileFirst Server:
>   FWLSE3051E: Invalid payload. See additional messages for details.

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuvu.png)

Comment: And now mention your MobileFirst version...

Comment: MobileFirst Version - **7.0.0** @idan Adar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20151001-1558 I am unable to confirm this. I successfully created a new project, add an application and to the application added the BlackBerry 6/7 environment.

1. Note that this environment is deprecated - meaning that most likely in the next MobileFirst Platform Foundation release it will be *removed*.
2. Try to start over in a *new* Eclipse workspace
3. Try to delete the wlBuildResources folder from your TMP directory
4. Make sure the location you have your Eclipse workspace has full permissions for your user.

Comment: Thanks @Idan Adar, Application 'BB6APP' deployed successfully with all environments.